# Intercept all child methods of base class

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, aop

I was wondering if the following is possible in C#:

A base class:

```
public abstract AbstractClass { }
```

And a few child classes:

```
public class ConcreteClass : AbstractClass 
{
   public int SomeMethod(){}
}


public class ImplClass : AbstractClass 
{
   public int SomeOtherMethod(){}
}
```

Is it possible to intercept all the methods from all the classes that are (directly or indirectly) inherent through the base class?

Thank in advance

Comment: Is this related to AOP? The title is misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C# support AOP, that may be possible

**[Code injection throw attributes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD)** : useing reflection to get its attributes of the class and calling desired method (Common usage)

[**Using IOC Frameworks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) like [Spring.Net](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html) may be another option. (Advanced options, using third party library)

**[ContextBound Objects approch](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8414/The-simplest-AOP-scenario-in-C)**: You may Inherit your classes from `MarshalByRefObject` or `ContextBoundObject` and using `IMessageSink`. (The hard way)

A nice article comparing the approches may be found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/aspect-oriented-programming-in-C-Sharp-net-part-ii/)

Answer (score 0):

This is feasible and if you follow the example from MSDN, you've got it, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Abstract methods have the following features:

An abstract method is implicitly a virtual method.
Abstract method declarations are only permitted in abstract classes.
Because an abstract method declaration provides no actual implementation, there is no method body; the method declaration simply ends with a semicolon and there are no braces ({ }) following the signature.